# IQueryable with RadioButtonList.SelectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, iqueryable, radiobuttonlist

May I use the selected Value from the `RadioButtonList` in the `IQueryable` to get selected values from a table?

I have `RadioButtonList` with `DataValueField="Code"`

My code is

```
public IQueryable<Tbl_name> GetValuesfromTable()
{
    return dbo.Tbl_name.Where(q => q.Code = (RadioButtonList.SelectedItem.Value)).OrderBy(c => c.Date_publication);
}
```

Please can you help me with this query?

Comment: Why do you need the `OrderBy`? Are you receiving an error? What error?

Comment: it actually works : return dbo.Tbl_name.Where(q=>q.Code== 1) . Order by is not necessary .. however I cannot use the value from RadioButtonList...

Comment: What happens when you try to use the value from RadioButtonList?

Comment: I updated my answer, try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the single value from that table. I am considering that `Code` is being serialized as a int:

```
public IQueryable<Tbl_name> GetValuesfromTable()
{
    var selectedCode = Convert.ToInt32(RadioButtonList.SelectedValue);
    return dbo.Tbl_name.Where(q => q.Code == selectedCode)
        .OrderBy(c => c.Date_publication);
}
```

Comment: The error is .. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' . However I have tried Convert.ToInt32(RadioButtonList.SelectedItem.Value) and does not work either...  The radio bautton value in general it is a number .... I have tried return dbo.Tbl_name.Where(q=>q.Code== 1) which works...

Comment: Actually I would like to get a list of values ( GridView ) from that Table_name.. but only where Code is equal to the value from the RadiobuttonList...

Comment: Put the `Convert.ToInt32` outside of the LINQ query. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot... it almost works.. with small correction that I added one more == so now it is (q => q.Code == selectedCode).... however in my case result of this query supposed to feel the GridView. when I insert a fixed number like (q => q.Code == 5 )etc..  so it will fill my gridview but the variable selectedCode does not.. My RadiobuttonList have AutoPostBack="true" ; My grid SelectMethod="GetValueFromTable" but something is still wrong.. I am trying to solve it still but I cannot .. Maybe I supposed to bind in some way the data from this function to the gridView SelectedIndexChanged?